# Testable Angular filter

Tags: javascript, angularjs, testing, filter

I've been using filters as seen here http://fiddle.jshell.net/NLcxL/5/ for a while now. The app I'm working on has many of filters very much like this.

```
   $scope.checkedEyeColor = {};
    var showAllEyeColor = true;
    $scope.filterEyeColor = function(result){
        return showAllEyeColor || $scope.checkedEyeColor[result.eyeColor];
    };

    $scope.$watch('checkedEyeColor', function(newval, oldval) {
        showAllEyeColor = true;
        angular.forEach($scope.checkedEyeColor, function(val) {
            if( val === true ) showAllEyeColor = false;
        });
    }, true);
```

Because I have all these in my controller file it is getting a bit unmanageable, so I was wondering how best to separate each filter out into its own filter js file, and then I believe I can write a test for each one? I know Angular has it's own .filter but I'm not having much luck.

Cheers
Tom

Comment: There is no filter in this fiddle... And what is exactly your problem with the filter from angular ?

Comment: Sorry, try http://fiddle.jshell.net/NLcxL/5/. I'll update the link.

Comment: This is where I'm up to my a custom filter: http://fiddle.jshell.net/6F6FH/1/ (not very far :P )